# DOS batch iterate over numbers in list

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I need to iterate over a list of numbers inside a DOS batch file. I have tried this:

```
for /l %%n in (10,13,14,15) do ( 
     REM do something 
)
```

But this doesn't seem to to work. What is the right syntax? There is very little proper documentation on batch file on www.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
    @echo off

    set nums=10,13,14,15

    for %%i in (%nums%) do (
      echo %%i
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
for %%n in (10,13,14,15) do ( 
     REM do something 
)
```